# Why doesn't oxygen form cyclic pentagonal compounds with itself?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Like we see in benzene, the bond angle between the oxygens of 104.5 degrees is very similar to a pentagon's interior angle of 108 degrees. The formal charges on the oxygens would all be zero and there's no dipoles, weak bonds or areas of high electron density so surely it would be somewhat stable and unreactive? So why don't they form?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51719/do-cyclic-oxygen-molecules-exist-and-their-theoretical-stability

Comment: See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35574 and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/431 - I should have checked for previous similar questions

Answer (score 7):

Sulfur does form ring compounds, so why not oxygen?

You're not wrong to wonder, but I think people are reacting to the implication that this species has:

> [no] weak bonds

Consider [hydrogen peroxide H-O-O-H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide) which has a central O-O bond. $\ce{H2O2}$ is fairly well known to decompose easily and generate radicals.

In fact, there are a variety of [peroxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxide) with that R-O-O-R motif. The peroxide refers to the O-O single bond.

In general, if you look up bond dissociation energies for R-O-O-R bonds, they're ~150-160 kJ/mol, about half the dissociation energy for $\ce{H3C}-\ce{CH3}$ and ***far*** less than the 498 kJ/mol for the $\ce{O2}$ double bond.

So it's perhaps *possible* to form such a ring, but with **five** O-O single bonds, it's likely to decompose readily, presumably into $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{O3}$ first, which would both have greater bond strengths.