# Is this a correct Lewis Dot structure for ozone?

Tags: lewis-structure, allotropes, oxygen

[image]

I drew a Lewis dot structure of ozone but when I look online it is a bit different. Can I make the single covalent bonds like a triangle that connects all three atoms or is that not allowed? If so, what rule is that and you describe it and its name?

Answer (score 1):

1. Dear OP, by the way, that 'trioxygen' is dubbed ozone.

---

For starters, **the Lewis dot structure for ozone does not look like that**. It is *not* a ring.

This is explained in this link: [Can ozone have a triangular structure?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22290/can-ozone-have-a-triangular-structure)

There it is also given (one of the simpler answers):

> In order to form a 3-member ring your electron pairs would have to bend at 60 degrees; the energy required to push naturally repulsive electrons so close together would make the molecule very unstable.

---

The correct Lewis dot structures along with resonance structures, can be shown as below:

[image]

This is from my NCERT textbook. You can check out the bonding and the Lewis dot structure.

[image]

------------------------------------------------------------------